# Horizontal movable menu with a click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPqxq.png

< ITEM2 ITEM3 ITEM4 ITEM5 ITEM6 >

This is what i am trying to achieve, by clicking the right arrow it should load the remaining menu item and same as left arrow but to left.

I am using asp.net! but can i achieve this by css and J Query or java script? Can anyone point out website that uses this ?

Comment: You need to include a link to some sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a JS Fiddle that should help with what you are trying to build.

A navigation menu that animates left or right.

http://jsfiddle.net/bYY39/

HTML

```
<div class='navigation'>
    <button type='button' class="left-arrow"><p><</p></button>
    <ul>
        <li class='item1'><a href="#">menu item1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">menu item6</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button type='button' class='right-arrow'><p>></p></button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

button {
    border:none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.navigation {
    width: 1000px;
}

.left-arrow {
    background: #3d69b9;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}

.left-arrow:hover {
    background: #69c;
}

.left-arrow p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.right-arrow {
    background: #3d69b9;
    border-left: 1px solid #69c;
    float: left;
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 60px;
}

.right-arrow:hover {
    background: #69c;
}

.right-arrow p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
}

ul {
    float:left;
    font-size: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 815px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

li {
    border-left: 1px solid #69c;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    width: 162px;
}

li a {
    background: #3d69b9;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%
}

li a:hover {
    background: #69c;
}
```

JS

```
$('.left-arrow').on({click: function() {
        $('.item1').animate({marginLeft:'0px'}, 500);
    }
});

$('.right-arrow').on({click: function() {
        $('.item1').animate({marginLeft:'-163px'}, 500);
    }
});
```

Comment: that is working @djrconcepts but in IE it all goes wrong. Expecially when i am increasing the content and the marginLeft in js, in ie it oly moves the very next li element! And in css overflow: hidden; may be not working in IE ! IE 10

Comment: I used <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > To solve this issue.